# Rails includes with where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to eager load some associations, but I want to do filtering on some of the sub-relations here is what I mean.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :my_model_details, dependent: :destroy
end

class MyModelDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :my_model
  belongs_to :track
  belongs_to :person
end
```

So if I want to get all `MyModel` objects which have details that belong to certain property with property name I would do this.

```
MyModel.includes(my_model_details: [:property, :person]).where('property.property_name = ?', 'Property name')
```

The reason why I want use `includes` instead of `joins`, is that I want to have my model details in grouped by the last property and person name. So I don't want to fire the N+1 query in that case.

**Ex**

If my query returns single `MyModel` object with two `MyModelDetail` records.

Where mymodeldetail id 1 has property id 1 and mymodeldetail id2 has property id 2. And they both belong to the same person.

So on my UI I would display this:

```
MyModel 1
  MyModelDetail 2 - Property name: 'some name' - Person: 'Bob'
```

Now what happens when I use my includes query is this :

```
MyModel.includes(my_model_details: [:property, :person]).where('property.property_name = ?', 'Property name')

SELECT "MY_MODEL".* FROM "MY_MODEL" WHERE (PROPERTY.PROPERTY_NAME = 'Prop')
```

If I use includes with where, join sql is not generated at all and so this query fails of course:

```
"PROPERTY"."PROPERTY_NAME": invalid identifier
```

Why is that, I'm using rails 4? How can I make it work with both joins and includes

Comment: Shouldn't table name be `properties`? Anyway, you need to add `.references(:properties)`

Comment: @BroiSatse I'm not sure where can I add it, can you expand on that, thanks

Comment: You can add it after `where` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be `properties`, because table name is pluralized according to CoC, try using `properties.property_name` instead

```
MyModel.includes(my_model_details: [:property, :person]).where('properties.property_name = ?', 'Property name')
```

As suggested by BroiSatse, add `.references(:properties)` to your query

Hope that helps!

Comment: same thing `"PROPERTIES"."PROPERTY_NAME": invalid identifier`

Comment: Did you add `.`references` as suggested by BroiSatse

Comment: yes I did, is this a rails 4 thing or is this how it's always been done? Generates super huge query with all the fields from `my_model_details`, I might end up with `left join` query in this case, will see works for now. THanks! Please edit your answer to include the references and I ll accept

Comment: Its not the Rails 4 thing, `include` works like this only.